# Nest a previously-flattened stream with Haskell Pipes

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

## Background

I have a *long* stream of *large* files whose contents I would like to stream in constant memory.

I'm using the [Haskell Pipes library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes) to model this stream with the following nested type:

```hs
Producer (FilePath, Producer ByteString IO ()) IO ()
```

In other words, the *outer producer* iterates over files, and the *inner producer* iterates over file chunks.

## Problem

For accounting purposes, I'd like to temporarily flatten this nested stream into something with the following type:

```hs
Producer FileStreamEvent IO ()
```

where:

```hs
type FileStreamEvent = NestedStreamEvent FilePath ByteString

data NestedStreamEvent a b = NestedStreamOpen  a
                           | NestedStreamChunk b
                           | NestedStreamClose a
```

It seems easy to write a function to perform this transformation:

```hs
flattenNestedStream :: Monad m
                    => Producer (a, Producer b m r) m r
                    -> Producer (NestedStreamEvent a b) m r
flattenNestedStream abs = for abs $ \(a, bs) -> do
    yield                $ NestedStreamOpen  a
    for bs $ \b -> yield $ NestedStreamChunk b
    yield                $ NestedStreamClose a
```

However, I'm not sure how to write the inverse transformation:

```hs
nestFlattenedStream :: Monad m
                    => Producer (NestedStreamEvent a b) m r
                    -> Producer (a, Producer b m r) m r
```

such that:

```hs
(nestFlattenedStream . flattenNestedStream) producer == producer
```

Can the function `nestFlattenedStream` be defined?

Comment: Can you describe more of what you are doing? Perhaps there is a solution which doesn't require you to re-nest the flattened stream.

Comment: I think, like @ErikR , a `Producer (FilePath, Producer ByteString IO ()) IO r` definitely shouldn't arise. The things piped and produced should generally be ordinary values. A `Producer FilePath (Producer ByteString IO) r` could  make sense, but is a little exotic.  (Something like could be necessary though.)  Can you say more about how you got this `Producer (FilePath, Producer a m r) m r` and where you are going with it?